# Partial option box visible issue in "Users and permissions" page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, stack-overflow-for-teams

On the "Users and permissions" page, the "ROLES" option dialogue box is partially visible due to the grid's height. I can see the full content by scrolling the dialogue box, but it would be nice if I could see the dialogue box when clicking the drop-down option.

**Screenshot for reference:**

[image: Role drop down]

Comment: We've added this to our bug backlog to fix in the future. It appears to only occur for invited users that haven't accepted the invite yet.

Comment: Can you confirm whether you are still seeing this issue? It appears it may have been fixed at some point from a different report. I am no longer able to reproduce it myself.

Comment: @animuson This design issue has been fixed, added a screenshot in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This design issue has been fixed.
Now able to see the full dialogue box.

**Screenshot for reference:**

[image: Alignment issue fixed]